# How should the footnote to BXVIII & BXIX in Kant's first Critique be understood? Does it even make sense?

Tags: logic, kant, terminology, explanation, critique-of-pure-reason

Note: I am avoiding the typical use of *object* and *subject* as *observed* and *observer* since it can become exceedingly confusing in this context.  I use *topic* in place of *object.*

The footnote to BXVIII & BXIX is the following:

> This method, accordingly, which we have borrowed from the natural philosopher, consists in seeking for the elements of pure reason in that which admits of confirmation or refutation by experiment. **Now the propositions of pure reason, especially when they transcend the limits of possible experience, do not admit of our making any experiment with their *objects,* as in natural science.** Hence, with regard to those conceptions and principles which we assume *à priori,* our only course will be to view them from two different sides. We must regard one and the same conception, on the one hand, in relation to experience as an object of the senses and of the understanding, on the other hand, in relation to reason, isolated and transcending the limits of experience, as an object of mere thought. Now if we find that, when we regard things from this double point of view, the result is in harmony with the principle of pure reason, but that, when we regard them from a single point of view, reason is involved in self-contradiction, then the experiment will establish the correctness of this distinction.

> Diese dem Naturforscher nachgeahmte Methode besteht also darin: die Elemente der reinen Vernunft in dem zu suchen, was sich durch ein Experiment bestätigen oder widerlegen läßt. Nun läßt sich zur Prüfung der Sätze der reinen Vernunft, vornehmlich wenn sie über alle Grenze möglicher Erfahrung hinaus gewagt werden, kein Experiment mit ihren Objekten machen (wie in der Naturwissenschaft): also wird es nur mit Begriffen und Grundsätzen, die wir a priori annehmen, tunlich sein, indem man sie nämlich so einrichtet, daß dieselben Gegenstände einerseits als Gegenstände der Sinne und des Verstandes für die Erfahrung, andererseits aber doch als Gegenstände, die man bloß denkt, allenfalls für die isolierte und über Erfahrungsgrenze hinausstrebende Vernunft, mithin von zwei verschiedenen Seiten betrachtet werden können. Findet es sich nun, daß, wenn man die Dinge aus jenem doppelten Gesichtspunkte betrachtet, Einstimmung mit dem Prinzip der reinen Vernunft stattfinde, bei einerlei Gesichtspunkte aber ein unvermeidlicher Widerstreit der Vernunft mit sich selbst entspringe, so entscheidet das Experiment für die Richtigkeit jener Unterscheidung.

Broken down, I get:

> This method, accordingly, which we have borrowed from the natural philosopher, consists in seeking for the elements of pure reason in that which admits of confirmation or refutation by experiment. Now the **propositions of pure reason**, especially when they transcend the limits of possible experience, do not admit of our making any experiment with their **objects,** as in natural science. Hence, with regard to **those conceptions and principles which we assume *à priori,***  our only course will be to view them from two different sides.

I will assume that, in the above text, the **objects** are the topics of the **propositions of pure reason**. Such objects include **those conceptions and principles which we assume *à priori* .** That is, they are the naive *à priori* assumptions of unexamined thought.

> We must regard one and the same conception, on the one hand, **in relation to experience** as an object of the senses and of the understanding, on the other hand, **in relation to reason,** isolated and transcending the limits of experience, as an object of mere thought.

Let *C* be some proposed naive *à priori* assumption.  *C* can be applied in one of two naive modes of reason. The first being **in relation to experience**.  Denote that mode as **E**.  The second mode being **in relation to reason**. Denote that mode as **V**.  For the sake of clarity we shall imagine that one mind **K** is conducting the critique.  **K** is examining the naive reasoning of another mind **N**.  The **propositions of pure reason** are in the mind of **K**. On the other hand, **those conceptions and principles which we assume *à priori,***  are in the mind of **N**.

**Are we to understand the sentence quoted immediately above as the following?** First **K** regards a case in which **N** applies *C* in mode **E**.  Next **K** regards a case in which **N** applies *C* in mode **V**.

Denote these as:

P1 := **K** watches **N** apply *C* in mode **E**.
P2 := **K** watches **N** apply *C* in mode **V**.

> Now if we find that, when we regard things from this double point of view, the result is in harmony with the principle of pure reason, but that, when we regard them from a single point of view, reason is involved in self-contradiction, then the experiment will establish the correctness of this distinction.

This could mean various things.

The most likely interpretation would be that P1 and P2 are presumed to be independent.  Thus if P1 is self-consistent in isolation, it is self-consistent regardless of whether P2 is involved.  So we might have P1 and P2. Meaning *C* applies to experience, *i.e.,* P1 as well as to objects of pure thought , *i.e.,* P2. Or we might have P1 and not P2.  Meaning *C* applies only to experience but not to objects of pure thought.

This is problematic to my mind, but far less so than one alternative interpretation. As it is worded, it seems to say, for example, that performing P1 alone could lead to self-contradiction, while performing P1 and P2 together produces no self-contradiction.  I shall reject this as nonsensical.

In this context, at least, Kant seems to mean conceptions involving sensation are experiences.  Conceptions of pure thought would pertain to analytic reasoning.  Thus, if P1 holds, but P2 fails, the conception under consideration is empirical, at least in part.

Does Kant's footnote really make sense? Can it be restated in a clearer form?

Comment: This seems to be related to Kant's treatment of the so-called [mathematical antinomies](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-metaphysics/#MatAnt), where he diagnoses the problem that leads to them as thinking of objects as both sensible and mind-independent, within possible experience and beyond it, at the same time. "Satisfying the demands placed by our rational capacity to think beyond experience, the thesis arguments offer what appears to be a satisfying resting-place for explanation. The antithesis charges that such a strategy fails to find any confirmation..."

Answer (score 0):

In this passage Kant says that the distinction between things-in-themselves and phenomena has to posited as a result of the *Transcendental Dialectic*. The *experiment* discussed here is the attempt of the power of Reason to reclaim the space of pure knowledge by overcoming the constraints established by the *Transcendental Analytic* on the Understanding and falling into dialectical contradictions. This, Kant says, constitutes an indirect proof of his formal/transcendental idealism (in the sense that thought doesn't have its own content but acquires it only in relation to a sensory intuition structured according to a spatio-temporal form) and so the distinction between phenomena and things-in-themselves (as well as the claim that only phenomena are knowable).

The passage that you cite is thus basically an announcement of the goal and the method of *Transcendental Dialectic*. Kant often uses terms borrowed from the exact sciences, ex. *epigenesis*, but also *experiment*.

It is a more complex issue of why such an experiment is indeed necessary, i.e. why, once we establish, with Kant, constraints on empirical thought in the *Analytic*, we have to re-consider metaphysics, that is: purely intellectual knowledge of things as they are in themselves. I cannot hope to fully explain that in this post, however the basic point is related to the idea of the systematicity of our empirical knowledge as a regulative ideal (which is basically identical to Reason as such).

Comment: Why would Kant write such a thing in the introduction, if it required a thorough understanding of the sequel to understand it?

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton His style is perhaps unclear but I don't find it strange that he announces the necessity to investigate the capacity of Reason to produce knowledge independently of all experience. The other part of the quote just says that, if this experiment concludes in Reason's entanglement in contradictions, we must necessarily posit a distinction between things in themselves and phenomena in order to resolve it. He doesn't yet assert the conclusion of the "experiment", but he anticipates it.

Comment: This is the part that doesn't make sense to me: "when we regard them from a single point of view, reason is involved in self-contradiction, then the experiment will establish the correctness of this distinction."  What is "this distinction"?  And what does it mean to decide in favor of it.  These are sentences with subjects and predicates.  It should be possible to analyze them structurally and determine their declarative meaning without evaluating their place is a grater context.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Kant speaks of "regarding things from a double point of view". This is the distinction between phenomena and noumena. So by "the distinction" he means the distinction between both points of view (it's important to remember that phenomena and noumena aren't two different worlds, just two different aspects of the same world; noumena are things in themselves, i.e. objects of our experience if we abstract from features of our senses altogether). [1/2]

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton To decide in favor of it is to say that space and time (forms of sensuous things) cannot be also forms of things independently of our experience of them, i.e. to assert that transcendental idealism is true. This is because objects of our experience, in abstracto, are just objects in space and time. These cannot be the same as things in themselves, because we have knowledge of objects as we experience them but not of things in themselves, and so: things in themselves cannot be spatiotemporal things, i.e. space and time have to be ideal, that is: features of the mind.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton This last inference (that space and time must be features of our mind, or rather, our senses) actually is quite confused, as most serious readers of Kant have acknowledged. This is a conclusion that Leibniz draws and Kant, being taught originally as a Leibnizian, seems to accept it as obvious (and I think barely argues for it). It is also irrelevant whether we speak of space and time or a *form of sensibility* in general. What matters is that this form is contingent, it's not a feature of thought as such.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Is this clear? I wrote this in a hurry but I can put this more systematically if it's not understandable.

Comment: It doesn't seem to address my question.  I'm trying to figure out (in the grammatical sense) how the different subjects, objects  and verbs relate to one another in the paragraph.  There is an issue of self-reference.  He is talking about applying reason to the reasoning process.  

Also, I don't understand the footnote under discussion to be directly addressing the forms of intuition of the transcendental.  The dichotomy that seems most relevant here is the distinction between empirical and pure reason.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I am not sure why do you find it necessary to sort it out gramatically. In any case, I don't think there's a problem with doing that once you know what Kant actually tries to convey in this pargraph although sentence-structure in the text is, I agree, rarely straightforward (some say that Kant mimics latin grammar but I don't know latin so I am unable to tell). I've been attempting to explain it. You're correct that he doesn't explicitly speak of forms of intuition. But the distinction that Kant anticipates to be necessary is between appearance and thing in itself. [1/2]

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Appearance is thing-in-itself as it appears, obviously. How it appears is dependent on the nature of the relation between our senses and their object (Kant even says that it consists solely of relations, cf. *Amphiboly* in *CPR*). Aristotle speaks of "common sensibles" to denote these features which objects of our senses have in general - Kant, for good reasons, asserts that these are space and time. He also calls them "forms of our sensibility". I am not sure what do you mean by "the transcendental" - Kant uses no such term, transcendental is always an adjective. [2/2]

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Kant makes a distinction between pure and impure (theoretical) Reason. I am unsure whether he speaks of "empirical Reason" albeit that would be the same as "impure Reason". "Pure" means here: used independently of all empirical knowledge in concreto.  "Impure" means here: conditioned by our actual empirical knowledge, i.e. Understanding, and applied only to systematize this knowledge according to the Ideas of Reason in their regulative employment (Kant explains that in detail at the very end of the Dialectic). "Pure" and "impure" distinguish two uses of the same faculty.

Comment: "Finally, that the transcendental aesthetic cannot contain more than these two elements, namely space and time, is clear from the fact that all other concepts belonging to sensibility, "

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton ?